# Connect Node with mysqli module?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to connect Node JavaScript with Mysqli. I have downloaded the mysqli module using following command.

```
npm install mysqli
```

And Then Create JavaScript file with following code.

```
var Mysqli = require('mysqli');

// incoming json 
let  conn  = new Mysqli ( {  
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
     password: "",
     database: "ll"
    } );

conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM post", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

But not able to connect to database.

I have used following Packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysqli

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

`conn.query`

Unless, of course, you wrote the code here again. I am sure you would have figured that out by now, but still... After all, this is the first thing that comes up when someone searches for mysqli nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The module which you're using seems to be a newer one and which is not stable.

Consider using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module which has been accepted by many developers, it has a great documentation and an active github community + google mailing list and IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to mysql db is the goal, then I suggest you to use `mysql` module.
install `mysql` module by running `npm install mysql`
below is the sample code for how to use the `mysql` module

```
const mysql  = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection(
{
    host:'your_host',             //localhost in your case
    user:'db_user',               // root in your case
    password: 'password',         //blank string in your case
    database:'your_db_name'       //'ll' in your case
});

//executing the queries
conn.query('SELECT * from post',function(err,result){ //result of the query is stored in 'result' and the error, if any, are stored in err
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
         console.log(result);
    }
});
```

click this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) for further information